# Is Hom functor a profunctor?

Tags: category-theory

A Hom functor is a functor defined as

$C^{op} × C → Set$

In more natural terms, it's a bifunctor which domain is the product category of C and the opposite of C.

A profunctor, as I understand it, is any bifunctor which is contravariant on the first argument and covariant on the second:

$\phi : D^{op} × C → Set$

Is the Hom functor indeed a term narrower than a profunctor? Where, specifically

$D = C$

Comment: The hom-functor is a _specific_ profunctor.

Comment: @ZhenLin why isn't that an answer?

Comment: I've always found the terminology "profunctor" terrible... Every time I hear it my first reaction is "What? A projective limit of functors?"

Comment: @NajibIdrissi, what term do you prefer?

Comment: @goblin I'm partial to "bimodule".

Comment: @NajibIdrissi, okay, but this makes it impossible to Google any information about these things. Profunctors are so fundamental, they need to have a unique identifying name IMO. I think I've heard "distributor" used, although I've never understood the intuition behind this term myself.

Answer (score 1):

As @zhen-lin comments, the hom-functor is a specific profunctor. This is the case as long as $\mathcal{C}$ is locally small.

Comment: Its always a profunctor, period. If $\mathbf{C}$ isn't locally small, then requiring your profunctors to be locally small is the wrong definition of "profunctor" for the application you have in mind.

Comment: Well, he gave a $Set$-profunctor definition, so I thought it would be appropriate to point out that certain hom-functors are left outside.

Comment: I'm sorry, I'm a beginner in category theory. Could you explain how the definition of profunctor could be extended to cover all Hom functions?

Comment: @BartekBanachewicz, to cover all hom-functors is somewhat ambitious (perhaps someone else can really explain this?). You can generalise profunctors to enriched categories, so a profunctor between two $V$-enriched categories $C$ and $D$ is a $V$-functor $D^{o} \otimes C \to V$, where $\otimes$ is the monoidal structure of $V$.

Comment: @BartekBanachewicz I'm not an expert, so take this with a grain of salt, but the hom-profunctor for a $Set$-enriched category $C$ is a functor $Hom(-, -) : C^{op} \times C \rightarrow Set$. In a $V$-enriched category $D$, it would simply be a functor $C^{op} \otimes C \rightarrow V$, where the product category $C^{op} \otimes C$ arises from the monoidal product of $V$ instead of that of $Set$.